# Families of Hessenberg varieties for $GL_n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reductive-groups, perverse-sheaves, springer-fibres

In short, the question is

> What do we know about the sheaf $\pi_*\underline{\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell}}$ given by the family of (very original, see below) Hessenberg varieties for $GL_n$? As a sum of shifted perverse sheaves, does every component have full support?

Fix a choice of Borel $B\subset GL_n$ (over any field of preference, say $\mathbb{C}$), and $\mathfrak{b}=\operatorname{Lie} B$. Let $\mathfrak{h}\subset\mathfrak{gl}_n$ be the sum of $\mathfrak{b}$ and the negative *simple* root subspaces. Consider the family of Hessenberg varieties
$$\tilde{\mathfrak{g}}_{\mathfrak{h}}:=\{(g,\gamma)\in GL_n/B\times\mathfrak{gl}_n\;|\;g^{-1}\gamma g\in\mathfrak{h}\}$$
with the natural map $\pi:\tilde{\mathfrak{g}}_{\mathfrak{h}}\twoheadrightarrow\mathfrak{gl}_n$ by $(g,\gamma)\mapsto\gamma$. The fibers of $\pi$ are the very original, so-called Hessenberg varieties. They are paved by affine spaces, see e.g. [1]. The generic fiber is the toric variety given by the Weyl chamber decompositions (where torus is the centralizer in $PGL_n$) [2, $\S$IV].

[1] *Tymoczko, Julianna*, [**Linear conditions imposed on flag varieties**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1353/ajm.2006.0050), Am. J. Math. 128, No. 6, 1587-1604 (2006). [ZBL1106.14038](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1106.14038).

[2] *De Mari, F.; Procesi, C.; Shayman, M. A.*, [**Hessenberg varieties**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2154181), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 332, No. 2, 529-534 (1992). [ZBL0770.14022](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0770.14022).

Comment: I'm not sure an answer is there, but look at the (unique) paper of Patrick Brosnan and Timothy Chow.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't read the paper before and I really appreciate the direction. If I just read it correctly, I think part of their main result, Theorem 127, answers my (second) question affirmatively on the regular locus, i.e. every component whose support intersects nontrivially with the regular locus has full support. I can't think of a way to generalize their method for now. I will add comment if I find anything.

Comment: And of course, their result works for the usual Hessenberg varieties for $GL_n$, not necessarily for $\mathfrak{h}$ in the "Hessenberg form"! For my interest I can reduce something about affine Springer fiber that I want to compute to Hessenberg varieties in this form (among with other things), but of course the question can be asked in general.

Comment: Would an affirmative answer imply that the locus where the fibers (i.e. the Hessenberg variety for $\gamma$) are big is small?  Dimensions can be calculated from the combinatorics in Tymoczko's paper (and there are papers that have done these calculations in various cases).

Comment: Examples on $GL_2$ and $GL_3$ suggest me that the naive way to use the dimension bound is not enough - not saying there couldn't be some smarter way.

Comment: On the other hand, it is possible to generalize the method/result of Brosnan and Chow in the following sense: the (sum of shifted) local systems on the regular semisimple locus as well as the stalks of the corresponding perverse sheaves are now combinatorially known. Thus one can compare the stalks given by the full support components with Tymoczko's result on the Betti numbers of the fibers. They agree iff the full support assertion is true. This definitely can be verified (for a not-so-large fixed n) by a program, though I am probably not going to write one soon...